# switch case array reading - javasound

Tags: java

Can anyone help through this problem?

I've set a textbox, got its text and made a switch case loop for each char of the string. Basically, i want to beep a certain frequency for each char typed by the user.

Unfortunately, it's not working

Before this change, i tested out with a freq variable that transformed the text(numbers) got from the textbox to an integer, and used it directly on the method. just like Emitir.tone(freq, 1000). It worked just fine.

**Emitir.tone is a method which receives an int x for certain frequency and int y for miliseconds and beeps in that exact x frequency for the exact y miliseconds

```
    String text = jTextField1.getText();
    char[] t = text.toCharArray();
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
         for(int i=1; i <= text.length(); i++){

            switch(t[i])
            {

                case 'a':
            {
                try {
                    Emitir.tone(150, 1000);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                     System.out.println("No sound device detected");
                }
            }
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 'b':
            {
                try {
                    Emitir.tone(200, 1000);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                     System.out.println("No sound device detected");
                }
            }
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 'c':
            {
                try {
                    Emitir.tone(300, 1000);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    System.out.println("No sound device detected");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Define "not working". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I typed abc in the textbox, and  i expected it to beep 150hz for 1000ms, 200hz for 1000ms and 300hz for 1000ms
It doesn't even beep like it did when I was working with the freq variable

Comment: Your loop boundaries are incorrect, and you increment i twice instead of just once, but if it doesn't even beep, then the Emitir.tone() is where the problem lies. Or you're not even calling this piece of code after you've typed abc in the text field. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at NewJFrame.jButton1MouseClicked(NewJFrame.java:231)
 at NewJFrame.access$200(NewJFrame.java:15)
 at NewJFrame$3.mouseClicked(NewJFrame.java:93)

Comment: String text = jTextField1.getText();
        if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
            int freq = Integer.parseInt(text);
            try {
                Emitir.tone(freq, 10000);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException exp) {
            }}

Comment: this was the last version, and it was beeping just fine

Comment: Read the stack trace you just posted. It tells you that, at line 231 of NewJFrame.java, in a method named jButton1MouseClicked, you're trying to parse the string "a" to an Integer. You just need to read. It also implies that you're using a mouse listener to handle a button press. That's not what you should do. You should use an ActionListener, as explained in the swing tutorial. A press nearly all buttons with my keyboard.

Comment: From what you posted, I also guess that the code you posted is never actually called. You should be able to figure that out by yourself, by using your debugger, or by simply adding a System.out.println() call, and see if something is printed or not.